# How to compare two text files and and change the sign of the data in powershell?

Tags: powershell, compare, row, multiple-columns

I have two text files which different columns and i want to compare two text files data ..and if 1 column data in 1st text file matches with another text file column (P-O-V) data, all the signs of the 2nd text file COLUMNS (JAN TO DEC) data have to change (+ TO - OR - TO +).

sample1.txt

```
100000 RS
200000 RS
300000 RS
```

sample2.txt

```
Sc,January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December,P-o-v,D L C N 


P2,3.24,5.67,-2.31,2.82,-2.93,-5.08,2.40,-2.90,2.90,-2.90,2.90,2.90,"001,100100,99001,P000000,U,D-0",PS

P2,3.24,5.67,2.31,2.82,2.93,5.08,2.40,2.90,2.90,2.90,2.90,2.90,"001,100000,99001,P000000,U,D-0",PS

P2,-3.24,5.67,-2.31,2.82,-2.93,5.08,2.40,-2.90,2.90,2.90,-2.90,2.90,"001,200000,99001,P000000,U,D-0",PS

P2,3.24,-5.67,2.31,-2.82,2.93,5.08,-2.40,2.90,2.90,-2.90,2.90,2.90,"001,300000,99001,P000000,U,D-0",PS

P2,-3.24,5.67,2.31,-2.82,2.93,5.08,-2.40,2.90,-2.90,2.90,-2.90,2.90,"001,300000,99001,P000000,U,D-0",PS
```

i want output file as output.txt

```
Sc,January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December,P-o-v,D L C N 
P2,3.24,5.67,-2.31,2.82,-2.93,-5.08,2.40,-2.90,2.90,-2.90,2.90,2.90,"001,100100,99001,P000000,U,D-0",PS

P2,-3.24,-5.67,-2.31,-2.82,-2.93,-5.08,-2.40,-2.90,-2.90,-2.90,-2.90,-2.90,"001,100000,99001,P000000,U,D-0",PS

P2,3.24,-5.67,2.31,-2.82,2.93,-5.08,-2.40,2.90,-2.90,-2.90,2.90,-2.90,"001,200000,99001,P000000,U,D-0",PS

P2,-3.24,5.67,-2.31,2.82,-2.93,-5.08,2.40,-2.90,-2.90,2.90,-2.90,-2.90,"001,300000,99001,P000000,U,D-0",PS

P2,3.24,-5.67,-2.31,2.82,-2.93,-5.08,2.40,-2.90,2.90,-2.90,2.90,-2.90,"001,300000,99001,P000000,U,D-0",PS
```

i have tried this code..which is not working

```
$sample1 = Get-Content -path "sample1.txt"
$Sample2 = import-csv -Path "sample2.txt" -Header "Sc","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December","P-o-v","D L C N"

  if ($sample2 -contains $sample1) {

 foreach($row in $sample2)
{
$row.January = "{0:N2}" -f (-1 * [float]$row.January)
$row.February = "{0:N2}" -f (-1 * [float]$row.February)
$row.March = "{0:N2}" -f (-1 * [float]$row.March)
$row.April = "{0:N2}" -f (-1 * [float]$row.April)
$row.May = "{0:N2}" -f (-1 * [float]$row.May)
$row.June = "{0:N2}" -f (-1 * [float]$row.June)
$row.July = "{0:N2}" -f (-1 * [float]$row.July)
$row.August = "{0:N2}" -f (-1 * [float]$row.August)
$row.September = "{0:N2}" -f (-1 * [float]$row.September)
$row.October = "{0:N2}" -f (-1 * [float]$row.October)
$row.November = "{0:N2}" -f (-1 * [float]$row.November)
$row.December = "{0:N2}" -f (-1 * [float]$row.December)
}

$sample2 | Export-CSV -UseQuotes Never -path "output.txt"

Write-Host "File  was modified" -foregroundcolor green
 } else { 
  Write-Host "File  was not modified" -ForegroundColor  red 
 }
```

Comment: Please provide better examples. In file 2 there is nothing that matches any of the text in file 1 exactly. (for instance, you can find a value `100000` but not `100000 RS`). What is that `RS` for ? Also, if a match can be found you want to change the signs on the **complete** data in file2 or just that row in the file???

Comment: sample1 has 2 columns i.e 100000 RS ...where 100000 from 1st file(sample1.txt) has to compare with P-o-v column in sample2.txt file

Comment: sample1 is tsv file with no column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to flip the signs on all values in columns "January".."December" if in that row the value from sample1.txt (first column only) can be found as the second value in the `P-O-V` column of file 2.
That 'P-O-V' column itself is a comma separated set of values.

Try

```
# import the csv data from file 2  (as per your example, it has headers)
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\sample2.txt'
# get the text from file 1 and loop over the lines
Get-Content -path "D:\Test\sample1.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    $valueToMatch = $_ -replace '\D+'  # just the number
    # try and find rows in the csv data with a matching value
    $matchData = $data | Where-Object { ($_.'P-o-v' -split ',')[1] -eq $valueToMatch }
    if (@($matchData).Count) {
        foreach ($row in $matchData) {
            # flip the signs in the month columns
            "January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
            "August","September","October","November","December" | ForEach-Object {
                $row.$_ = '{0:F2}' -f (-[double]$row.$_)
            }
        }
    }
}

# export the updated data. I'm setting parameter `UseQuotes` to `AsNeeded`, because column `P-o-v` is a 
# comma delimited string and should not be split apart into several fields
$data | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\output.csv' -UseQuotes AsNeeded -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @Intern99 using your own examples they do. Are you looking at the correct output file?

Comment: i made a few changes ..and it was working..Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

For better performance, I suggest loading the numbers to compare the files by into a *hash set* first:

```bash
# Import the TSV file and load the values from the first column into a hash set.
$hashset = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] (
  Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" sample1.txt -Header Number, Unused
).Number

# Import the CSV file and, in ever row that contains a hash-set entry
# in the 2nd ","-separated field of the "p-o-v" column, invert all column
# values that contain a floating-point number.
Import-Csv sample2.txt |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($hashset.Contains(($_.'p-o-v' -split ',')[1])) {
      # Invert the signs in all relevant columns.
      foreach ($prop in $_.psobject.Properties) {
        if ($prop.Value -as [double]) {
          $prop.Value = if ($prop.Value.StartsWith('-')) { $prop.Value.Substring(1) } else { '-' + $prop.Value }
        }
      }
    }
    $_ # Output the (potentially modified) row object.
  } | ConvertTo-Csv  # replace with Export-Csv ... as needed in your real code.
```

Comment: i have tried this one..data signs from jan to dec not fliping

Comment: @Intern99, with your sample data, they do,  namely in all rows of `sample2.txt` but the first. Perhaps your sample data isn't representative?